# rich center a renderable in Layout

Tags: python, rich

I've been using the rich library and I have a layout that displays a table at the top of the layout, but I want it to be centered. I've looked in the documentation and wasn't able to find anything. Layout doesn't take a justify argument.

Here is the table code

```
team_info = Table(title='Team Info')
team_info.add_column("Team Name", justify='center', no_wrap=True)
team_info.add_column("League", justify='center', no_wrap=True)
team_info.add_column("Season", justify='center', no_wrap=True)

team_info.add_row("Boston Celtics", "NBA", "2019-2020")
```

Here is a snippet of the Layout section of the code

```
team_stats_display = Layout()
team_stats_display.split_column(
    Layout(team_info, name='team info', ratio=3),
    Layout(name='stats', ratio=7)
)
```

Here is the results

[image: Output]

Is there any way to center the table?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your team info table with an `Align` object:

```
from rich.align import Align

team_info = Align.center(team_info, vertical="middle")
```